# How to request a list of blocks using bitcoin-cli?

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I'm trying to figure out how to use `bitcoin-cli` effectively to request a list of 50 blocks.

As far as I am aware, `bitcoin-cli getblock` list  does not work. Also how to best extract information out of the `getblock` output.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot as there currently no way in Bitcoin Core's RPC to get multiple blocks with one command. You will have to issue multiple `getblock` commands. If you use a JSON-RPC client programmatically, you can use JSON-RPC's batched requests in order to have to only send one JSON-RPC request to execute multiple RPCs and get the results back in one response.

As for how to extract the information, you will need a JSON parser to extract the information. You can use verbosity level 2 in order to get the transactions decoded as well instead of just their txids.